# Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mern

Please help, I am getting this error

```
src/app/middlewares/authentication.ts:16:17 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

16             req.user = user;
```

I have created the .d.ts file and also included it in tsconfig file. Still I am not able to run this code

Please find attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 31):

1. Create a *types* folder in your src directory
2. Create a folder within the types folder with the name of the package you intend to extend. (In this case *express*).
3. Create an *index.d.ts* file in that folder

```
 src/
   - types/
    - express/
     - index.d.ts
```

4. add this code to the index file

```
import express from "express";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: Record<string,any>
    }
  }
}
```

5. remember to update your *tsconfig.json* file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots" : ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

This should work

Comment: Is it required for the `user` object to be optional? I'm not getting errors (so far) with it not being so.

Comment: Other answers didn't work for me, only creating a "express" folder inside types/ worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: 'Express' is not defined is what it says when I try to use it in my passport.ts file

Comment: The solution helped. It solved the issue I was having as well.

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck on the same problem earlier. Here is how I solved it.

1. I created a separate directory called @types in my project for declaration merging to work.
2. Next I created a file in it called index.d.ts with following content. Please pay attention that we need to declare our own request within global. Also, importing express is important as well.

```
import * as express from "express"
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user? : Record<string,any>
        }
    }
}
```

3. I added the following line under compilerOptions in my tsconfig.json.

```
 "compilerOptions": {
     ...other settings,
     "typeRoots": ["@types", "node_modules/@types"],
     ...other settings
 }
```

And that's it. It should works with these changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually VS code is not showing any error. The error comes when I run the code

Comment: It's still giving an error. Please help me

Comment: Hi, @PiyushGarg, did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: NOTE that you have to put `typeRoots` inside the `compilerOptions` as he is showing in the answer. I had them outside. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: In the tsconfig.json's typeRoots attribute cares about ordering. Make sure you specify your local types before the node_modules types! Use `["./types", "node_modules/@types"]` over `["node_modules/@types", "./types"]`

Comment: For my setup, I needed to move my custom `types` into my `src` folder vice the project root.

Answer (score 4):

Just install types for Passport.js:

```
npm install -D @types/passport
```

Comment: this worked!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

interface IDecode {
    address: string,
    role: string,
    iat: number,
    exp: number
  };

 interface RequestWithUserRole extends Request {
    user?: IDecode,
}


 const parseToken = (secret: string) => 
  async (req: RequestWithUserRole, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try{
      const token  = req.headers?.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
      // console.log(req.headers?.authorization);
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).json({message: 'Token not  found'})
      }
      const decodedData = <IDecode> jwt.verify(token, secret);
      req.user = decodedData;
      // console.log(decodedData);
      return next();
    }
    catch(e) {
      return res.status(500).json({e})  
    }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This I would use. its easier and not messing with configs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick walkaround if you are doing a quick prototype or following a tutorial
`(req as any).user`

*NB: Do not use this in a real production app, because it would make your code dirty and it's not scalable.*

Answer (score 0):

1. These were the variables I want to use in the Request object. In your `/src/types/express/index.d.ts` you should put::

   ```
   export {}

   declare global {
     namespace Express {
       export interface Request {
         idUser?: string
         email?: string
         username?: string
         // extra variables you want to use in req object
       }
     }

   }
   ```
2. In your `tsconfig.json`:

   ```
   {        
       "compilerOptions": {
           // other settings
           "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]  // it's important to put first your path file otherwise it won't work
           // other settings
       }
   }
   ```

This should also work for you. Good luck!